# Chrome shows a password suggestions for an input field

Tags: jquery, html, input, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have one input field with type text and jQuery Datepicker. A weird thing happening is that when I click on that input field, chrome shows a password suggestion.

```
<input name="registration" type="text" placeholder="MM.JJJJ">
```

When I remove the name then it stops suggesting passwords.

[image]

Comment: Try  `<input name="registration" autocomplete="off"`

Comment: can you replicate the issue in fiddle or snippet??

Comment: @User863 autocomplete is stopping input suggestions but not password suggestions

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai how can you get the op's autofill in the fiddle?

Comment: @Ikt may be the `name` attribute is same with any other password fields. try changing it

Comment: @Liam because its not password. its a text field

Comment: Wiat, this isn't a password field? This makes no sense, we're going to need a [mcve]

Comment: This comment is worth gold: *"When I remove the name then it stops suggesting passwords"*

Answer (score 4):

Do you have a input before that one, called something like `email` or `username`?

I've seen Chrome look at an input field and decide all by it's self that the field after it is a password field, and try to autocomplete it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `autocomplete="disabled"`

Chrome stopped supporting `autocomplete="off"` that's why  `autocomplete="off"` isn't working but it doesn't understand if you use `autocomplete="disabled"` that's why this works for now