# Stop chrome auto filling / suggesting form fields by id

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, autocomplete

Ok so...like many other posts this is driving me nuts. Chrome is continually offering autocomplete suggestions for fields that I would rather it not be on. It, along with the soft keyboard take up the whole page which blocks the view for the user / the form is not intended to fill our the users data but rather a new address that would be previously unknown.

So far I've got these both on

`<form autocomplete="off">`

and

`<input autocomplete="randomstringxxx">`

Their effect is noticed and chrome is no longer filling the whole form - but it STILL wants to suggest single field suggestions for each element in my form.

I've finally realised that its now picking up the id/name fields from my form elements.

i.e the below will give me a list of names I have used before.

`<input id="contact_name" name="contact_name">`

Can anyone suggest a way to stop this without renaming the elements? They are tied to fields in my database and ideally I would not have to manually rename and match up these together.

example -

https://jsfiddle.net/drsx4w1e/
with random strings as autocomplete element attribute  - STILL AUTOCOMPLETING

https://jsfiddle.net/drsx4w1e/1/
with "off" as autocomplete attribute. - STILL AUTOCOMPLETING

https://jsfiddle.net/6bgoj23d/1/
example no autocomplete when labels / ids/ name attr are removed - NOT AUTOCOMPLETING

example

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using autocomplete="off" for all form inputs?

Comment: yes - it just ignores it

Comment: this is strange, because it doesn't do autocomplete for me when its set to off. would you mind adding your html to your question?

Comment: see my jsfiddle

Comment: on your inputs you have put autocomplete="None" this will turn the autocomplete on. either remove autocomplete="None" or change it to autocomplete="off"

Comment: I've updated it to random strings (i thought I had already) but it still does it, also with "off". The only way I can stop it is to take away the identifier from the elements ID and Name attribute.

Comment: *Random strings as i've read in many posts, and it does stop the full autocomplete from working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243165/discussion-between-rydog-and-lewis-morris).

Comment: [From this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57573715/7656460) you must use `autocomplete="disabled"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this isn't ideal because it changes the name of the inputs but it only does it temporarily. Changing the name attribute is the only way I found that completely removes the autocomplete.

**This solution is all in JS and HTML but I think it would be better if it was implemented with a server side language such as PHP or Java.**

I found *autocomplete="none"* works best for chrome but it doesn't fully turn off auto complete.

### How it works

So, on page load this solution adds a string of random characters to each input name.

```
eg. 'delivery_contact_name' becomes 'delivery_contact_nameI5NTE'
```

When the form is submitted it calls a function (submission()) which removes the random character that were added. So the submitted form data will have the original names.

See solution below:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <form autocomplete="none" id="account_form" method="post" action="" onsubmit="return submission();">
     
        <div class="my-2">
          <label for="delivery_contact_name" class="">*</label>
          <input autocomplete="none" class="form-control" id="delivery_contact_name" maxlength="200" minlength="2" name="delivery_contact_name" required="" type="text" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="my-2">
          <label for="delivery_telephone" class="">Telephone*</label>
          <input autocomplete="none" class="form-control" id="delivery_telephone" maxlength="200" minlength="8" name="delivery_telephone" required="" type="tel" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="my-2">
            <label for="delivery_address_1" class="">Delivery Address*</label>
            <input autocomplete="none" class="form-control" id="delivery_address_1" maxlength="50" minlength="2" name="delivery_address_1" required="" type="text" value="">
          </div>
          <div class="my-2">
            <label for="delivery_address_2" class="">Delivery Address*</label>
            <input autocomplete="none" class="form-control" id="delivery_address_2" maxlength="50" minlength="2" name="delivery_address_2" required="" type="text" value="">
          </div>
          <div class="my-2">
            <label for="delivery_address_3" class="">Delivery Address</label>
            <input autocomplete="none" class="form-control" id="delivery_address_3" name="delivery_address_3" type="text" value="">
          </div>
          <div class="my-2">
            <label for="delivery_address_4" class="">Delivery Address</label>
            <input autocomplete="none" class="form-control" id="delivery_address_4" name="delivery_address_4" type="text" value="">
          </div>
          <div class="my-2">
            <label for="delivery_address_postcode" class="">Delivery Postcode*</label>
            <input autocomplete="none" class="form-control" id="delivery_address_postcode" maxlength="10" minlength="6" name="delivery_address_postcode" required="" type="text" value="">
          </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
  </body>
  <script>
    
      //generate a random string to append to the names
      const autocompleteString = btoa(Math.random().toString()).substr(10, 5);

      //get all the inputs in the form
      const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");

      //make sure script calls function after page load
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        changeInputNames();
      });

      //add random characters to input names
      function changeInputNames(){
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
          inputs[i].setAttribute("name", inputs[i].getAttribute("name")+autocompleteString);
          }
      }

      //remove the random characters from input names
      function changeInputNamesBack(){
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
          inputs[i].setAttribute("name", inputs[i].getAttribute("name").replace(autocompleteString, ''));
          }
      }
     
      
    function submission(){
      let valid = true;
      //do any additional form validation here
      if(valid){
        changeInputNamesBack();
      }
      return valid;
    }
    
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry I passed out was way too late, thanks. This is a great solution, why didn't I think of it!!  Will test and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @rydog for his help. I've changed it into a function that I've put into a my js file as I didn't want to manually add to each page / fire on every page - I have also added the submit event handler with js rather than adding to the on submit of the form.

GREAT SOLUTION by Rydog

```js
function stop_autofill() {

    //generate a random string to append to the names
    this.autocompleteString = btoa(Math.random().toString()).substr(10, 5);

    this.add_submit_handlers = () => {
        document.querySelectorAll("form").forEach(value => {
            value.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
                this.form_submit_override(e)
            })
        })
    }

    //add random characters to input names
    this.changeInputNames = () => {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.input_elements_arr.length; i++) {
            this.input_elements_arr[i].setAttribute("name", this.input_elements_arr[i].getAttribute("name") + this.autocompleteString);
        }
    }

    //remove the random characters from input names
    this.changeInputNamesBack = () => {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.input_elements_arr.length; i++) {
            this.input_elements_arr[i].setAttribute("name", this.input_elements_arr[i].getAttribute("name").replace(this.autocompleteString, ''));
        }
    }

    this.form_submit_override = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        this.changeInputNamesBack()
        e.currentTarget.submit()
        return true
    }

    this.setup_form = () => {
        //get all the inputs in the form
        this.input_elements_arr = document.querySelectorAll("input");
        this.changeInputNames();
        this.add_submit_handlers();
    }

    //make sure script calls function after page load
    this.init = () => {
        if (document.readyState === "complete") {
            this.setup_form()
        } else {
            let setup_form = this.setup_form
            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (e) {
                setup_form()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

on the page that needs it

```
<script>
    af = new stop_autofill()
    af.init()
</script>
```